# The 'pack' function in Perl

Tags: perl, pack, unpack

**My Perl program:**

```
say 'Hexadecimal notation in a Perl script';
my$str = pack 'H*', '987456123';
print unpack('H*', $str), "\n";
print unpack('h*', $str), "\n";
```

**Output:**

```
Hexadecimal notation in a Perl script
1. 9874561230 # Why is it showing zero here?
2. 8947652103
```

In my `1` result why is it showing zero? What is cause of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have odd number of chars in `987456123` and `H*` packing requires even, so it assumes zero for the last pair (`98`, `74`, `56`, `12`, and `30` at the end).

From [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html):

> Starting from the beginning of the template to pack(), each pair of characters is converted to 1 character of output. [...]
>   If the length of the input string is not even, it behaves as if padded by a null character at the end. Similarly, "extra" nybbles are ignored during unpacking.

Comment: some times we use `H*` and some times `*H`.why we use like that.what is the difference b/w those?please let me know

Comment: @OlegG, "[If the length of the input string is not even, it behaves as if padded by a null character at the end.](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html)"